# MultiOSBoot Problems

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

I want to install Ubuntu on my laptop to run along side windows. I had recently installed Windows 10 TP and now want to try something new. I want to keep windows. I also only had a single hard drive. I've been reading about this and it seems a bit too confusing for me. Is there something special I must do or can I just partition my hard drive for windows and Ubuntu after the Live CD loads and I open the installer? I am new to Linux and have no idea what to do.

Comment: Boot op your Ubuntu CD/USB start the installer, and when asked how to installer, choose `Install next to Windows 10`. The Ubuntu Installer will automatically search the os that is installed on your System.

Comment: Is this a new system with UEFI or older with BIOS only. And if newer did you install Windows in UEFI or BIOS/CSM boot mode? If not sure post this: `sudo parted -l` from Ubuntu live installer. How you boot install media is how it installs. Shows install with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Boot op your Ubuntu CD/USB start the installer, and when asked how to installer, choose Install next to Windows 10. The Ubuntu Installer will automatically search the os that is installed on your System. – but one thing both os must be on same mode i mean uefi or legecy